# How to add Mac OS minimize style in windows form in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, macos, styles, operating-system

I have a project which is need to change default window minimize style & add new style. New style such as- Mac OS window minimize style.

Is it possible to add another minimize style in C#? If is it possible to change the minimize style, so please help me..

Comment: Please don't do that.  Windows is not Mac OS.

Comment: I know it. But I just wanna add Mac Os minimize style in my C# windows project & Nothing else.

Comment: Don't do that either.  Users expect Windows applications to work like Windows.

Comment: Dont try like Mac , try something better than Mac for our windows :)

Comment: I agreed with u. But i wanna just customize it nothing else.